# The display name of gmail does not change even after changing it on settings

Tags: gmail, google-contacts, email, mobile, iphone

In Gmail settings I went the section "Send email as" and set it to "Alphabeta", six months ago. However when I sent an email last week, my display showed as "A B". My username is "alphabeta" so, I do not know where "A B" comes from.

How can I set the display name correctly so that recipients of my emails see the right display name?

Answer (score 0):

The post ["I cannot change my display name on the sent emails"](https://outlook.uservoice.com/forums/284136-outlook-com/suggestions/20512546-hi-i-cannot-change-my-display-name-on-the-sent-em) , in OutlookUserVoice, helped me with this.

One of the answers mentions that there might be an issue with this if one is logged in in other devices. Indeed, I was logged in in my phone too, and the iPhone settings have their own option for "Account name", and that is where the name "A B" was coming from. Apparently, that display name was preferred over the 'official' one in gmail settings, at least when sending emails from the iPhone.

So, I changed my display name on the iPhone, and I hope that solves the issue. If it does not, then I will log out of all my devices and hopefully that does solve it.

Comment: Please [edit] this answer with final results later...